# CartoDB Torque script causing JQuery UI conflict

Tags: carto, carto-js

I am using the torque library hosted here: https://github.com/CartoDB/torque

I am using it in a viz.json-based visualization (so the torque layer is defined in the cartodb web console.) When I try to include a torque layer **when I have imported JQuery**, the visualization freezes with the following stacktrace:

 `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function          cartodb.mod.torque.js:6 
 cdb.geo.ui.TimeSlider.cdb.geo.ui.InfoBox.extend.updateSlider               cartodb.uncompressed.js:676
 Backbone.Events.trigger           cartodb.mod.torque.js:5 
 L.undefined.L.TorqueLayer.L.CanvasLayer.extend.setKey       cartodb.mod.torque.js:5 
 (anonymous function)      cartodb.mod.torque.js:3 
 r.time      cartodb.mod.torque.js:3 r._tick`

The torque visualization only works if I remove my import of JQuery, which breaks other parts of the website, such as the `tabs()` function.

Below are the imports I am using, the first works for Torque but breaks `tabs()`, the second works for `tabs()` but breaks Torque.

For Torque:

 `<script src="dist/torque.uncompressed.js"></script> 
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.uncompressed.js"></script>`

For no Torque:

    `<script src="dist/torque.uncompressed.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.uncompressed.js"></script>`

The `tabs` error occurs at:
`$('#windowtabs').tabs();`
`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

You should be able to simulate this problem by trying to load the different sets of libraries as I posted -- on the one hand the torque visualization will freeze (if jquery is loaded), on the other hand, the torque visualization will work, but .tabs() will create an error.

Comment: Hi @wovenhead
Please, could you share your entire code?

Comment: The code is proprietary. I have included the relevant parts. The error occurs at `$('#windowtabs').tabs();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to try to use CartoDB.js without jQuery in order to avoid conflicts between these libraries: http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.11/cartodb_nojquery.js

Another approach that you could follow is to use jQuery migrate, as explained in this issue: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/issues/414

Comment: It looks like the problem may have been fixed in the pull request related to issue #414 you linked. I can't confirm this myself because I'm no longer on this project. I'll accept your answer for now--but you may want to check for yourself that it works, and edit with your results